# When is FILE flushed?

Tags: c++, c, windows, libc, fflush

I have a good old C FILE file descriptor under Windows that is used by an output stream to write data to. My question is simple and yet I could not find the answer:

**When is the content flushed to disc assuming I don't call fflush?**

The stream constantly receives data and it seems that the content is flushed quite often, but what is the rule for flushing it?

Comment: Pretty sure it's up to the OS.

Comment: BTW actually the code uses a wxTextOutputStream that uses a wxFFileOutoutStream that uses a wxFFile. But that only encapsulates a FILE structure so I guess the fflush mechanism is the interesting thing here...

Comment: If it's buffered,then it's flushed once the buffer is full.And I don't quite understand what you mean by FILE structure (fopen,fwrite,....)

Comment: Yeah, think so, too. So maybe it is more a VS2010 C runtime question?

Comment: Sry, just wanted to hint. I mean the FILE file descriptor that is used by fopen, fwrite etc

Comment: So, buffer size depends on the os specific runtime then?

Comment: @anhoppe, Since you are using the CRT, you can define your own buffer size using [`setvbuf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/setvbuf.html) though. Also, I think that the default buffer size is `BUFSIZ` defined in __stdio.h__. This value is compiler dependant.

Comment: @anhoppe The other issue is that even if you control the FILE buffer with setvbuf, that gives no guarantee that the data will be written to the disc. There could be other layers of buffering that are outside your control.

Comment: @AnishRam: `BUFSIZ` depends on the library implementation, not the compiler.

Comment: @DevSolar, yeah. You're right.

Comment: When you a) Close the file b) Unmount the device. On Linux there is a `sync` command. Otherwise you can't guarantee the data has landed on a physical device.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the library implementation can determine the output stream not to refer to an interactive device (and *only* then), the stream will be fully buffered, i.e. it will be flushed when the buffer (by default of `BUFSIZ` size) is full.

If not fully buffered, a stream can be line buffered, i.e. it will be flushed when an `'\n'` is written (or the buffer is full, if your line is *really* long), or unbuffered.

(ISO/IEC 9899:1999, chapter 7.19.5.3 "The `fopen()` function", paragraph 7. Don't have a newer version of the standard at hand, but AFAIK this didn't change.)

What constitutes an "interactive device" is implementation-defined. (Chapter 5.1.2.3 "Program execution", paragraph 6.)

The general idea is that file output should be fully buffered whereas terminal output be line buffered (or unbuffered, as Jesse Good correctly pointed out).

Both the buffering policy and the buffer size can be changed via `setvbuf()`. Note that any such change must happen *before* you start accessing the stream, which is somewhat obvious once you think about it.

Comment: @anhoppe: I've actually *implemented* `<stdio.h>`, and *boy* you better learn to read the fine print when you do that... :-D

Comment: +1 Additionally, the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) specifies that `BUFSIZ` should be _at least_ 256.

Comment: `In all other cases (interactive device or unable to determine), the stream will be line buffered` I don't think that is true, it can unbuffered also (which is how the terminal is on windows).

Comment: @JesseGood What the standard literally says is that the stream is fully buffered if and only if it can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.  Otherwise, it can be line buffered or unbuffered.

Comment: @JesseGood: Good catch. I've been in a bit too much of a hurry when I wrote that. The standard reference was wrong as well.